# The bot skips a track every time one has ended. Can anyone figure out what happened?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I designed a music bot that queues playlists of songs but the weird thing is it skips a song every time one has ended. For example, if I have 3 songs in queue, the track number would be 0,1,2 and it will skip 0 when the current song finished.

Here is my play command

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("play a song from YouTube.")
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Searches for a song and plays it")
                .addStringOption(option =>
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("search keywords").setRequired(true)
                )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Plays a playlist from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the playlist's url").setRequired(true))
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("Plays a single song from YT")
                .addStringOption(option => option.setName("url").setDescription("the song's url").setRequired(true))
        ),
    execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        // Make sure the user is inside a voice channel
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.reply("You need to be in a Voice Channel to play a song.");

        // Create a play queue for the server
        const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild);

        // Wait until you are connected to the channel
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder()

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song") {
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            
            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply("No results")

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})

        }
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist") {

            // Search for the playlist using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
            })

            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.reply(`No playlists found with ${url}`)
            
            // Add the tracks to the queue
            const playlist = result.playlist
            await queue.addTracks(result.tracks)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} songs from [${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})** have been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(playlist.thumbnail.url)

        } 
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search") {

            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            let url = interaction.options.getString("searchterms")
            const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: interaction.user,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return interaction.editReply("No results")
            
            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            embed
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})
        }

        // Play the song
        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
        
        // Respond with the embed containing information about the player
        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
}
```

Here is my show queue command:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("queue")
        .setDescription("shows first 10 songs in the queue"),

    execute: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        const queue = client.player.getQueue(interaction.guildId)

        // check if there are songs in the queue
        if (!queue || !queue.playing)
        {
            await interaction.reply("There are no songs in the queue");
            return;
        }

        // Get the first 10 songs in the queue
        const queueString = queue.tracks.slice(0, 10).map((song, i) => {
            return `${i}) [${song.duration}]\` ${song.title} - <@${song.requestedBy.id}>`
        }).join("\n")

        // Get the current song
        const currentSong = queue.current

        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setDescription(`**Currently Playing**\n` + 
                        (currentSong ? `\`[${currentSong.duration}]\` ${currentSong.title} - <@${currentSong.requestedBy.id}>` : "None") +
                        `\n\n**Queue**\n${queueString}`
                    )
                    .setThumbnail(currentSong.setThumbnail)
            ]
        })
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this? I think it might be something wrong on how the bot queue the songs. I am using node.js v19 and discord.js 14.

Answer (score -1):

just run

```
npm i discord-player@5.3.2
```

in cmd

new versions of discord player are incredibly buggy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).